# Online algorithm to find shortest subarray containing all k-elements

Tags: data-structures, arrays, maximum-subarray

We have given array of $n$ integers in the range $[1, k]$. We want to design algorithm that can modify the array and also find the length of the shortest subarray containing at least one of each integers in the range $[1,k]$. $k$ can go up to 50, but $n$ can be large number, up to 100000.

I know that the offline version with fixed array can be solved in $O(NK)$ with sliding window across the array, but I don't know how to extend this or another algorithm to make it work online.

Please give me some hints where to start.

Comment: I guess I was a bit too quick about the specific time complexity. But do try to implement the sliding window algorithm in an online version.

Comment: I don't have much experience with sliding window algorithms, is it possible to do the sliding window in online fashion, because it should scan the whole array for each update, since one number can change a lot, for example if on beginning the interval is very big, after one update it will become smaller.

Comment: For interval, I mean the subarray containing all integers from 1 to K

Comment: You should store some additional information that would help you update the data structure.

Comment: But still, when you update one element it changes a lot, I don't see how can we reduce to updating only one single element

Comment: You won't be updating just a single element; but hopefully you will be able to update much faster than the offline algorithm.

Comment: Truth is, I don't know how to solve this.